# <a> element in div slightly elevated from the bottom

Tags: html, css

I am making a blog website and have an a element in post heading div :

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>A Simple Blog</title>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/stylesheets/blogstyle.css">
  </head>

  <body>
    <h1 class="heading">BLOG</h1>


<div class="post">
  <div class="post-heading">
    <a class="post-title" href="/blog/5066549580791808">The Dark &amp; Light of Francisco Goya</a>
    <div class="post-date">March 1, 2015</div>
  </div>
  <div class="post-content">In the summer of 1969, as the violence intensified in Northern Ireland, the poet Seamus Heaney was in Madrid. Like any tourist, he went to the Prado, but not specifically, he later said, “to study examples of art in a time of violence.” He found, nonetheless, that some of Francisco Goya’s work on display “had the force of terrible events…. All that dread got mixed in with the slightly panicked, slightly exhilarated mood of the summer as things came to a head in Derry and Belfast.” He found Goya’s work “overwhelming,” and was fascinated at the idea of an artist confronting political violence “head-on.” In his poem “Summer 1969,” he wrote of his time in the heat of the Spanish city while Belfast burned:</div>
</div>


  </body>

</html>
```

stylesheet code :

```
body {
    position: relative;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif, Times;
    background-color: #FFFFE6;
    width: 1000px;
}

.post-heading {
    height: 45px;
    border-bottom: 2px solid black;
    position: relative;
}
.post-title {
    font-family: "URW Palladio L","URW Gothic","Times New Roman",Times,serif;
    font-size: 30px;
    color : #444;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.post-date {
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    color: #999;
}

.post-content {
    margin-top: 5px;
    font-family: Georgia,Times New Roman, sans-serif;
}
```

Here is a preview of the website from my screen :

[image]

There is a gap between the highlighted `<a class="post-title">` and the parent `<div class="post-heading"></div>` elements. You will have to focus a little between the blue box and the black border at the bottom to see the gap in the picture.

This gap is driving me crazy!

Why does this gap appear and how do I get rid of it??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the fixed height from the `.post-heading` element:

```
.post-heading {
    /* height: 45px; */
    border-bottom: 2px solid black;
    position: relative;
}
```

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/jju6nk3x/)

Comment: Finally. Thanks a lot! This has happened to me before but never realized the fixed height was causing this!